# how to download decrypted file without writing to disk first

Tags: php

I have a script that can take an mp3 file on disk for a given `$path` variable (ie: `/var/recordings/file.mp3`) and send it to the browser to be player by a media player.  Here is the code:

```
//Send the media asset to the browser
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($path));
header('Content-Disposition: filename="recording.mp3"');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
print file_get_contents($path);
```

I now store the mp3 files in question in encrypted form, so I now read the file in question into a string and decrypt it using an encryption class.  I'd like to now send this decrypted file directly to the browser without outputting it into a file, and then having PHP read the contents of that file.  Is it possible?  I would assume I could just do `print $decrypted_string` but how would I specify the file size?

Comment: `strlen($decrypted_string)`? However, what's the point of storing them encrypted if you're just going to decrypt them upon sending?

Comment: Sure you want to hold the whole file content in memory, even twice (encrypted and decrypted)? That won't scale. Imagine 150 users requesting files in parallel... You need to decrypt on-the-fly whilst reading the file and sending the content.

Comment: Marc- the reason for storing them encrypted is for compliance reasons.  I can send them to the browser unencrypted once the user authenticates (the file is sent with a no-cache header and over an https connection).

Comment: @ arkascha- would this works?  $file_string = get_encrypted_file;  $file_string = decrypt($file_string);  That would store the file only in memory once?

Answer (score 2):

First decrypt it. Then calculate the size the `strlen` function. Use that value as `Content-Length` headers value.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
$decrypted_string = decrypt_mp3($contents);
header('Content-length: ' . strlen($decrypted_string));
echo $decrypted_string;
```